# no animation when pressing back button on header in android fragment

Tags: android

I have a back button on my fragment when I press on it I don't see any animation (like in the activity that circle that I see for a split second when I press the back button)

I'm adding a back button to the fragment in the code like this:

```
    mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.tyto_setup_title);

    mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp));

    mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(MyFragment.this).commit();
        }
    });
```

here is my XML for the header inside the fragment

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/AppBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/MYTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyToolbarTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyToolbarTitle"
            app:popupTheme="@style/MyTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mySkipButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="@string/tyto_live_stream_action_bar_label"
                android:textColor="@color/my_color_white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

do you know how to show the animation (that split second animation) when i press the back button ?

Comment: what do you mean by "that split second animation"?

Comment: @RamyMalak when u normally press a back button you get verification for the press like it highlights itself for a split second and in my case, it didn't

Comment: Can you make a gif of this issue? To create a gif save a video using Android Studio and convert video using a website such as ezgif or any other. You can upload gifs to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

```
mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (getActivity() != null) {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down)
                        .remove(MyFragment.this)
                        .commit();
            }
        });
```

**slide_down.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

**slide_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-100%" />
</set>
```

Comment: R.anim.slide_up and R.anim.slide_down is 2 animations you did yourself right ? i dont have them ofc

Comment: you can still use android.R.anim.slide_down

Answer (score 0):

if you mean the ripple effect. then you should replace the textView with Button or warp your textview with cardview and set this cardview as clickable.

solution1:-

```
   <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/AppBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/MYTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyToolbarTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyToolbarTitle"
            app:popupTheme="@style/MyTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/myCloseButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="@string/tyto_live_stream_action_bar_label"
                android:textColor="@color/my_color_white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

solution2:-

```
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/AppBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/MYTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyToolbarTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyToolbarTitle"
            app:popupTheme="@style/MyTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/myCloseButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tyto_live_stream_action_bar_label"
                    android:textColor="@color/my_color_white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is:

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

or

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

on the back button `View`.

Comment: i dont have a back button view as I'm adding it dynamic in the code